# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't see windows 10 usb stick installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb

i have 16.04 installed. i used ubuntu live cd to allocate a new space by dividing root partition.

now i put windows usb, boot from it but it can see my flash but cant boot into windows. i used all slots of usb

[image]

as you can see in the picture, still seems i have 800 gb in root drive but i divided it in Ubuntu live OS? why did not it apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you installed Windows 10 on a USB stick.  Your image is of the content of a hard drive, not a USB stick.

You would have to select the USB device to see the content of the USB stick.  You can select specific devices by clicking on the `GParted` menu and point to the USB device.  Windows isn't install on your `/dev/sda` drive.  The USB drive would be a device higher than `/dev/sda`, in your case.  If you have two devices, your internal `/dev/sda` and a USB drive.  You find it listed as `/dev/sdb`.

Gparted shows one drive at a time.  You can use `gnome-disks` to see the list of drives on the same screen.  Gnome-disks will display your USB drive as a Pen Drive Icon.

Comment: No i wanted to show there is no allocated part. i made devsda2 as 500 gb adnd 380 gb was unallocated, when i was in try ubuntu without installation. But  now as you can see, it did not apply? because of that windows usb cant  be seen?gnome disks show also i can see flash in drives